# Translate only the default twig value (Nesting twig filters)

Tags: templating, filter

Is it possible to write this as a one-liner?

```
{% if craft.entries.section('mypage').one() != null %}
  {{ craft.entries.section('mypage').one().title }} {# If title is provided - use, but don't translate #}
{% else %}
  {{ "My page"|t }} {# Default value should be translated #}
{% endif %}
```

This is my solution so far, however this will translate both the default and the provided title. Is it possible to group these filters somehow to not translate the title?

```
{{ craft.entries.section('mypage').one().title|default("My page")|t }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `t` filter *inside* the `default` filter, this way it only applies to the default value:

```twig
{{ craft.entries.section('mypage').one().title|default("My page"|t) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moritz's answer should be correct. For readability I'd like to propose something like that:

```
{% set mypage = craft.entries.section('mypage').one() %}
{% set title = mypage ? mypage.title : "default title"|t %}


{{ title }}
```